# serverless not recognizing s3 bucket is deleted through console

Tags: amazon-s3, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I created an s3 bucket through serverless then deleted it through the console.  Serverless is not recognizing the bucket is deleted.

How do I get it to see bucket doesn't exist anymore?
Am I missing something else?

Error message:

```
Serverless: Operation failed!

Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

An error occurred: AttachmentsBucket - ets-attachment-bucket already 
exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:827046125128:stack/
s3-aws-tutorial2-dev/1a8a5350-eb64-11e8-9abf-128e2cab805c.

Stack Trace --------------------------------------------

ServerlessError: An error occurred: AttachmentsBucket - ets-attachment-
bucket already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-
1:827046125128:stack/s3-aws-tutorial2-dev/1a8a5350-eb64-11e8-9abf-
128e2cab805c.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to make a change, but the cloudformation stack already exists. You need to go into the aws console, cloudFormation, delete the stack associated with your serverless and then re run your deploy.